# How to find the source of "Got unexpected auxiliary data with level=1 and type=2"

Tags: journalctl

I see many entries of "Got unexpected auxiliary data with level=1 and type=2" in journalctl, but there is no hint where these are generated. The number of log entries is high. I cannot brain-link these entries with specific services.

How can I find out which service generates the "Got unexpected auxiliary data with level=1 and type=2" messages?

Comment: I'm curious if adding `--output=with-unit` to your `journalctl` command makes any difference?

Comment: As you say in your answer that you can reproduce it on a fresh install, it would help to describe the exact steps that lead to the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be somewhat brute-force but you can list all enabled services with

```
systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled
```

You can likely disregard most of the services listed as being fairly vanilla. For the ones you want to take a look at, use

```
journalctl -u *servicename*
```

Tedious but it should work. Might be better to use a loop to examine each service and `grep` for your error message.

Comment: Thank you! I went through all, but nothing yielded a result. But your suggestion lead to another observation: The times when the entries are logged were about 10 seconds apart, and that is an interval where a PHP script monitors some services (runs tests against services). The timesamps coincide exactly. No I know where to look further, because I can simply test step-by-step with that script to find out which of the monitoring tests causes the entries.

Answer (score 0):

After more tests we found that with debug logging enabled, every service restart where systemctl is involved leads to exactly three "Got unexpected auxiliary data with level=1 and type=2" entries in the journal. This is also true on fresh operating system installs of CentOS and Alma Linux. It is still unclear why these entries are logged, but they seem to be totally normal and expected.